# Why won't my pygame program display my image

Tags: python, image, pygame, blit

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height),0,32)
player=pygame.image.load("cat.png")

while True:
    screen.fill(0,255,0)
    screen.blit(player,(100,100))
    pygame.display.flip
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit
            exit(0)
```

This refuses to show my cat picture, and there is no error in the shell. I'm sorry if i'm making a dumb error but i am very new to both this site and python.

Answer (score 2):

```
pygame.display.flip
```

Should be:

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

And

```
        pygame.quit
```

should be:

```
        pygame.quit()
```

Without the parenthesis, you're not calling the functions.

Comment: And `pygame.quit` should be `pygame.quit()`.

Comment: @IstvanChung: Thanks for catching that.